# How do I prevent multiple users from running Google Apps script code at the same time in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am sharing a google script sheet to multiple users, I just want to prevent the same user to run the script at the same time. What do I have to do? Is it by code or by settings only?

Comment: By code. You can try `LockService`

Answer (score 2):

As @TheMaster said in a comment, `LockService` is the way to go. Specifically, you want [`LockService.getDocumentLock()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service#getDocumentLock()) or [`LockService.getScriptLock()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service#getScriptLock()) depending on how your script is set up.

Example of how to use the lock service in Apps Script:

```
var timeoutMs = 5000;  // wait 5 seconds before giving up

var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();  // or LockService.getDocumentLock();
lock.tryLock(timeoutMs);

try {
    if (!lock.hasLock()) {
        var msg = 'Skipped execution after ' + (timeoutMs / 1000).toString() + ' seconds; script already running.';
        console.log(msg);
        try {
            // If script is being run from a user UI context (ex: from a Menu option),
            // gracefully alert the user we gave up
            SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(msg);
        } catch (e2) {}
    } else {

        //*** ADD CODE YOU WANT TO PROTECT HERE

    }
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    try {
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        ui.alert("Error", e ? e.toString() : e, ui.OK);
    } catch (e2) {}
}

SpreadsheetApp.flush();
lock.releaseLock();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a great answer. That was precisely what I was looking for.